# PostGIS - Finding most remote point using ST_MaximumInscribedCircle?

Tags: postgis

I have a database of points coordinates taken from OSM. My geometry column is called `wkb_geometry`. I am trying to find the most remote point (by distance to the next nearest point). I was hoping to use the new `ST_MaximumInscribedCircle` function and then order by radius to find the most remote point. Below is the code I have so far. It runs but returns `0` for the radius. [The example](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MaximumInscribedCircle.html) on the PostGIS website is for a polygon.

```
SELECT
  osm_id, name,
  geom.radius,
  geom.center,   
  geom.nearest   
FROM
  australian_points AS t,
  LATERAL ST_MaximumInscribedCircle(t.wkb_geometry) AS geom
  ORDER BY geom.radius ASC
;
```

Comment: The table ```australian_points```  is a points layer not a polygon layer

Comment: You need to collect the points into a `MULTIPOINT` using  `ST_MaximumInscribedCircle( ST_Collect( t.wkb_geometry))`

Comment: It's probably more efficient (and more correct?) to find the nearest point to each point with a NN query, and then take the one with maximum distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an index structure supporting (spatial) *(K)NN* searches like the PostGIS `GIST` extension, this is trivially executed with

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    p1.id,
    p1.geom,
    ST_Distance(p1.geom, pn.geom) AS dist
  FROM
    australian_points AS p1
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT
        p2.geom
      FROM
        australian_points AS p2
      WHERE
        p1.id <> p2.id
      ORDER BY
        p1.geom <-> p2.geom
      LIMIT
        1
    ) AS pn
) q
ORDER BY
  dist DESC
LIMIT
  1
;
```

Here

- we find the *nearest neighbor* to each point using a *(K)NN* query (a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` "*loop*" in conjunction with the index-optimized `<->` distance operator)
- and then filter for the highest `dist` value (`ORDER BY dist DESC LIMIT 1`)

---

If you need true **geoidal surface distances**, you'd want to implement a `CAST` to `GEOGRAPHY`; change the query to use

- `ST_Distance(p1.geom::GEOGRAPHY, p2.geom::GEOGRAPHY)` (*spheroidal* calculation)
- `p1.geom::GEOGRAPHY <-> p2.geom::GEOGRAPHY` (*spherical* calculation)
  respectively.

(*Note that a `CAST` to `GEOGRAPHY` is possible only for geographic reference systems!*)

**But beware:**

This can only ever be as performant with an appropriate index on the `CAST`, e.g.

```
CREATE INDEX
  ON australian_points
  USING ( (geom::GEOGRAPHY) )
;
```